# How to find closed form of summation

Tags: summation

How do you find the closed form of this summation?

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\log_4 n-1} i^2 $$

I know the following: $$\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

How can I use this to find the closed form of my summation? 
Thanks

Comment: kindly check the first equation to see if $n^2$ is suppose to be $i^2$.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it

Answer (score 2):

Guide:

Assuming $n$ is a power of $4$.

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\log_4 n-1} i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{\log_4 n-1} i^2$$

Now, you can use the fomula that you listed in your question. Just replace $n$ in the formula by the relevant expression.